# How do I display a image as a background in a bootstrap container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, background-image

I am pretty new to web development but I am trying to make a website at the moment. I am running into an issue where I can not get an image to load as a background for a container. You know like those run of a mill carbon copy bootstrap websites. I have read a few posts on here but they didn't help resolve my issue.

File Structure:

```
/css/
   master.css
   bootstrap.min.css
   font-awesome.min.css
/imgs/
   pho.jpg
/scripts/
   bootstrap.min.js
index.html
```

Html:

```
  <div class="container-fluid" id="landing">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <ul class="nav nav-fill" id="topNav">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link" id="orderOnline"><i class="fa fa-globe" aria-hidden="true"></i> Order Online</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link" id="contactPhone"><i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i> 1-843-123-4567</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link" id="hours"><i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> 10:00 - 23:59</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link" id="myAccount"><i class="fa fa-user-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> My Account</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="nav-link" id="cart"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></i> Cart</a>
          </li>
        </ul><!-- end of topNav -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-transparent">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Low-Country Thai Cuisine</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>

          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
              <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Menu</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav> <!-- end of navbar -->
      </div><!-- end of landing -->
    </div><!-- end of row -->
```

CSS:

```
#landing {
  background-image: url('../imgs/pho.jpg') no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: 100% auto;
  -moz-background-size: 100% auto;
  -o-background-size: 100% auto;
  background-size: 100% auto;
}
```

So what am I doing wrong? And why?

Answer (score 0):

You're specifying two background properties in one single property. So, the shorthand property for background:`background` should be used. 
It should be written as the following:

```
#landing {
  background: url('../imgs/pho.jpg') no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: 100% auto;
  -moz-background-size: 100% auto;
  -o-background-size: 100% auto;
  background-size: 100% auto;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That was the solution. I really appreciate it.